# Sharing linter configurations between projects

Tags: python, static-analysis

I want to share configuration of linter (flake8, pylint, whatever) between multiple python projects.

I researched this topic a bit and didn't find any suitable solution except for https://pypi.org/project/nitpick/ which doesn't work - my custom config is ignored.

Basically I want something similar to https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs - a "single source of truth" for liner configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution for you can be to combine the template tool [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) with [cruft](https://cruft.github.io/cruft/), a tool to manage linter configuration this boilerplate over the life of a repository.